# Content-Based Routing in nginx

Tags: nginx

Does anyone know if it's possible to have nginx route a post request to a particular server based on the content in the request body, via POST?

For example, I have a POST request being sent to a web server containing XML. I'd like to be able to read the XML and determine where to send the request.

Comment: were you able to achieve this?